# getting javaScript value in C# on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, javascript, string, windows-phone-8, invokescript

I'm trying to make a string using invokeScript but I keep getting a error,

my code looks like this

```
string corectLogin = (string)webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", ("document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent || li.innerText;"));
```

and the server side code looks like

```
<div id="loginMessage" class="show">

    Message from server

</div>
```

Using firebug on firfox I get the correct response "Message from server", but on the phone I get no value at all so it must be something in my c# that is going wrong or not calling the invokescript function right.

Thanks

Comment: same problem on windows 8 app where it just returns "system._ComObject"

Comment: Well, your JavaScript doesn't return anything, does it?

Comment: the `document.getElementById('loginMessage').textContent || li.innerText;` correctly returns "Message from server" when I debug in webbrowser also in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the "running" of scripts from within the webbrowser control.

```
            webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
```